# How to create a Oracle Datasource in ssrs 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, oracle10g, ssrs-2008-r2

I have to connect to Oracle database through ssrs because my reports are pointing to Oracle DB. When I tried to create a datasource, it throws error ORA-1254:TNS:Nolistener.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is actually ORA-12541? Sounds like you have something wrong with your configuration, or you just can't connect the server.

[OraFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12541):

> An ORA-12541 error occurs when the listener for the destination server
>   is down or unreachable when you try to connect. This can be due to the
>   listener not being started or being incorrectly configured, or it can
>   be due to a network connection problem.